# Why am I getting this runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'Solution::node' (solution.cpp)

Tags: c++, list, runtime-error, c++17

I was solving a question on leetcode [1409. Queries on a Permutation With Key](https://leetcode.com/problems/queries-on-a-permutation-with-key/), but I am getting this runtime error I don't know why. I am unable to debug this error.

Problem Statement:Given the array queries of positive integers between 1 and m, you have to process all queries[i] (from i=0 to i=queries.length-1) according to the following rules:

```
In the beginning, you have the permutation P=[1,2,3,...,m].
For the current i, find the position of queries[i] in the permutation P (indexing from 0) and then move this at the beginning of the permutation P. Notice that the position of queries[i] in P is the result for queries[i].
```

Return an array containing the result for the given queries.

My approach: I created a linkedlist to store the integers form 1 to m.
Then according to each query, I pass it to a function `getpos()` which returns the position of that query in the list and then updates it as per the directions given in problem statement.
This return value is then added to a result vector which is supposed to be the final answer after all queries are processed.

I have added comments to better understand my code

```
class Solution {
public:
    struct node {
        int data;
        node* next = NULL;
    };
    node* addnode(node* head, int data) {
        if(head == NULL) {
            head = new node;
            head->data = data;
        }
        else {
            node* temp = head;
            while(temp->next != NULL) { temp = temp->next; }
            temp->data = data;
        }
        return head;
    }
    int getpos(node** head, int data) { //To get position of given query
        int count = 0;
        node* temp = *head;
        node* prev;
        while(temp->data != data) {     //runtime error:member access within null pointer of type 'Solution::node' (solution.cpp); SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:32:21
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
            count++;
        }
        prev->next = temp->next; //searched node deleted
        temp->next = *head;      //add the searched node to beginning of the list
        *head = temp;            //udapate head
        return count;            //we have position stored in count;
    }
    
    vector<int> processQueries(vector<int>& queries, int m) {
        node* head = NULL;
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++) { head = addnode(head,i+1); }
        int n = queries.size();
        vector<int> result;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) { result.push_back(getpos(&head,queries[i])); }
        return result;
    }
};
```

Please debug and explain the cause of the error. I face many runtime errors which I fail to debug.

Comment: Can you please add the headers you include and your main function?

Comment: I am writing this code in leetcode's console, where you can only write the function that returns the answer while the input/output is handled by leetcode itself. As far I know we can assume every necessary header already present in leetcode. I have added the link to question, you can paste my code and run it there.

Comment: @AdityaHugay Posters here are reluctant to go to third party sites. A better way to operate would be use your own compiler, write your own main function and copy and paste your code to leetcode when you are ready. This would allow you to create your own test cases (very important) and use your own debugger (also very important). Both these things would mean you learn more from using leetcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `add_node` function is bugged. Just take a deep breath and look at the code. `add_node` should allocate a node using `new` every time it is called. Ask yourself how many times and under what circumstances your version allocates a new node?

I'm sure you can see that your code only allocates a new node when `head` equals NULL, therefore it must be bugged.

Incidentally if you wanted a linked list why didn't you use `std::list`? You would have avoided the mistake you made.

Comment: It showed the runtime error elsewhere, that's why I never thought about addnode. Thank you for pointing it out. I was unsure about how will I remove the element(node) after getting its position from that list.

Comment: It's how C++ often works. The crash is caused by an error somewhere else. Is your second comment about removing elements from a `std::list`? Just use `std::find` and `std::list::erase`

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember that next time.